# Downlaod the csv file

Tags: php, ajax, csv, fopen

I have a function that is called via ajax which creates a csv file, the response code coming back is 200 but the file doesn't download - the function I have is:

```
private function createCvsObject($array){
    $f = fopen('ActiveReports.csv', 'w');

    foreach($array as $projectNumber=>$project){
        fputcsv($f, $project, ',');
    }

    fclose($f);
}
```

As far as I know, it creates the csv file - but it wont download it. Is there some step I am missing in here so that it will auto download the file after creating it?

Comment: And where, and how you try to download the file ?

Comment: By "cvs", do you mean "csv"?

Comment: So you're creating a file called 'ActiveReports.cvs' on your server, what are you doing with it then?

Answer (score 2):

Just add

```
header('Content-Type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=ActiveReports.csv');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
readfile("ActiveReports.csv");
```

after `fclose($f);`

Comment: He also needs to print the file contents.

Comment: And watch out in case two users are trying to create the download at the same time

Comment: @LogicLooking - t-code has now added the `print the contents` bit with `readfile("ActiveReports.csv");` which reads the file you've created and sends it to the current php output stream (ie to the browser)

Comment: I dont see his additions